# No Overload for method 'SavehighScore' take 0 arguments in XNA

Tags: c#

I have an error in XNA, in my gameover update state, on the if statement for highscores. It says the following message error message:
'No Overload for method 'SavehighScore' take 0 arguments'.

But below it I have written the method, not sure what to do now?

Heres my full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace PickUpTheCrewGame
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class PickUpTheCrewGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        public enum State
        {
            Menu,
            Playing,
            Gameover,
        }

        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        SpriteFont messageFont;
        SpriteFont playerScoreFont;
        Texture2D backgroundTexture;
        Rectangle backgroundRectangle;
        Texture2D menuImageTexture;
        Rectangle menuImageRectange;
        Texture2D gameoverImageTexture;
        Rectangle gameoverImageRectangle;
        Sprite BlueBall;
        Sprite GreenBall;
        Sprite OrangeBall;
        Sprite PinkBall;
        Sprite RedBall;
        Sprite c;
        Sprite YellowBall;
        public Texture2D menuImage;
        public Texture2D gameoverImage;

        //---player scoresyer
        int playerScore = 0;
        int highScore = 0;

        //Lists
        List<sharks> sharks = new List<sharks>();
        List<Sprite> crew = new List<Sprite>();
        List<int> highscoreList = new List<int>();

        //highScoreList.Add(score);


        //Set First State
        State gameState = State.Menu;

        HUD hud = new HUD();

        public PickUpTheCrewGame()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            //sreen size
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
            menuImage = null;
            gameoverImage = null;


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            //enable the mousepointer
            //IsMouseVisible = true;
            base.Initialize();
        }

        public bool IsHighScore()
        {
            if(playerScore >highScore)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Save(string filename)
        {
            System.IO.TextWriter textOut = null;
            try
            {
                textOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename);
                Save(textOut);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (textOut != null) textOut.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Save(TextWriter textOut)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
                {
                    textOut.WriteLine(crew1.location.X);
                    textOut.WriteLine(crew1.location.Y);
                }

                foreach (sharks enemySprite in sharks)
                {
                    textOut.WriteLine("Shark");
                    textOut.WriteLine(enemySprite.location.X);
                    textOut.WriteLine(enemySprite.location.Y);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        public void Load(string filename)
        {
            System.IO.TextReader textIn = null;
            //try
            //{
            textIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
            Load(textIn);
            //}
            //catch (Exception e)
            //{
            //    throw e;
            //}
            //finally
            //{
            if (textIn != null) textIn.Close();
            //}
        }

        private void Load(TextReader textIn)
        {
            foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
            {
                crew1.location.X = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
                crew1.location.Y = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            }
            foreach (sharks enemySprite in sharks)
            {
                enemySprite.location.X = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
                enemySprite.location.Y = int.Parse(textIn.ReadLine());
            }
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            hud.LoadContent(Content);
            //-----LOAD THE MENU BACKGROUND-----
            menuImageTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("menuImage");
            menuImageRectange = new Rectangle(0, 0,
                Window.ClientBounds.Width,
                Window.ClientBounds.Height);

            //------LOAD INGAME BACKGROUND-----
            backgroundTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Background");
            backgroundRectangle = new Rectangle(
             0, 0, // top left hand corner
             Window.ClientBounds.Width,
             Window.ClientBounds.Height); // size of screen display

            //GAMEOVER IMAGE BACKGROUND
            gameoverImageTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("gameoverImage");
            gameoverImageRectangle = new Rectangle(
                0, 0,
                Window.ClientBounds.Width,
                Window.ClientBounds.Height);


            //-------Captains crew-------

            c = new Sprite(new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(0, 0),
                  Content.Load<Texture2D>("WhiteBall"), Color.White);

            BlueBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(640, 450),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlueBall"));
            crew.Add(BlueBall);

            GreenBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(250, 600),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("GreenBall"));
            crew.Add(GreenBall);

            OrangeBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(115, 400),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("OrangeBall"));
            crew.Add(OrangeBall);

            RedBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(500, 600),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("RedBall"));
            crew.Add(RedBall);

            YellowBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(800, 400),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("YellowBall"));
            crew.Add(YellowBall);

            PinkBall = new Sprite(new Vector2(25, 175),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("PinkBall"));
            crew.Add(PinkBall);

            //--------Sharks------
            sharks s = new sharks(new Vector2(1000, 200),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);
            s = new sharks(new Vector2(900, 200),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);
            s = new sharks(new Vector2(800, 200),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("BlackBall"));
            sharks.Add(s);

            messageFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("messageFont");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            //----------This gets the time value---------
            float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            //--------------keyboard input---------------
            //Exit
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                this.Exit();
            //Save
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                Save("test.txt");
            //Load
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.L))
                Load("test.txt");

            //Directional Movement
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                c.velocity.X = -350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                c.velocity.X = 350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                c.velocity.Y = 350;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                c.velocity.Y = -350;


            //UPDATING PLAYING STATE
            switch (gameState)
            {
                case State.Playing:
                    c.Update(elapsed);
                    foreach (Sprite cr in crew)
                    {
                        cr.Update(elapsed);
                    }
                    c.col = Color.White;

                    //----sharks intersects with whiteball----
                    foreach (sharks s in sharks)
                    {
                        if (c.bounds.Intersects(s.bounds))
                        {
                            gameState = State.Gameover;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (sharks s in sharks)
                    {
                        s.Update(elapsed, c.location);
                    }



                    //hud.Update(gameTime);
                    //----sprites intersect with whiteball----
                    foreach (Sprite crew1 in crew)
                    {
                        if (c.bounds.Intersects(crew1.bounds))
                        {
                            //gameState = State.Gameover;
                            playerScore += 1;
                            crew1.bounds.X = 10000;
                            crew1.bounds.Y = 10000;
                            crew1.location.Y = 10000;
                            crew1.location.X = 10000;
                            break;
                        }
                    } break;


                //UPDATING MENU STATE
                case State.Menu:
                    {
                        //Get keyboard state
                        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                        {
                            gameState = State.Playing;
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                //UPDATING GAMEOVER STATE
                case State.Gameover:
                    {
                        //Get keyboard state
                        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Back))
                        {
                            if (IsHighScore())
                            {
                                highScore = playerScore;
                                SavehighScore();
                            }
                            playerScore = 0;
                            sharks.Clear();
                            crew.Clear();
                            gameState = State.Menu;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }


        private void SavehighScore(string filename)
        {
            TextWriter textOut = null;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(filename))
                    File.Delete(filename);

                textOut = new StreamWriter(filename);
                textOut.WriteLine(highScore);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (textOut != null) textOut.Close();
            }


            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            switch (gameState)
            {
                //DRAWING PLAYING STATE
                case State.Playing:
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTexture, backgroundRectangle,
             Color.White);
                        c.Draw(spriteBatch);
                        //FOR EACH CREW DRAW
                        foreach (Sprite cr in crew)
                        {
                            cr.Draw(spriteBatch);
                        }
                        //FOREACH SHARK DRAW
                        foreach (sharks s in sharks)
                        {
                            s.Draw(spriteBatch);
                        }

                        hud.Draw(spriteBatch);

                        spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, playerScore.ToString(),
                new Vector2(200, 0),
                Color.White);

                        spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, " Player Scores - ",
                            new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
                        break;


                    }
                //DRAWING MENU STATE
                case State.Menu:
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(menuImageTexture, menuImageRectange, Color.White);
                        break;
                    }
                //DRAWING GAMEOVER STATE
                case State.Gameover:
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(gameoverImageTexture, gameoverImageRectangle, Color.White);
                        spriteBatch.DrawString(messageFont, "Your Final Score was - "  + playerScore.ToString(),new Vector2 (0,0), Color.White);
                        break;
                    }
            }


            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Heres my error message: the error message appears at the 'SavehighScore();'

```
case State.Gameover:
                    {
                        //Get keyboard state
                        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Back))
                        {
                            if (IsHighScore())
                            {
                                highScore = playerScore;
                                SavehighScore();


  }
                        playerScore = 0;
                        sharks.Clear();
                        crew.Clear();
                        gameState = State.Menu;
                    }
                    break;
                }
```

Here my SavehighScore method:

```
private void SavehighScore(string filename)
        {
            TextWriter textOut = null;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(filename))
                    File.Delete(filename);

                textOut = new StreamWriter(filename);
                textOut.WriteLine(highScore);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (textOut != null) textOut.Close();
            }


            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

The objective is here is that its meant to save the highscores. Hopefully, save it to a file, is what i'm trying to achieve here.

I am new to xna and still learning.
Thank you,

Comment: Obviously you need to pass a parameter, looks like a file name, to the place where you call `SavehighScore`

Comment: So in the SavehighScore, I do SavehighScore(filename)

Comment: Perhaps you should post more code so we could browse all your LOC.

Comment: @shaneo yes, as long as you have a `filename` variable defined, otherwise pass in a static string of the filename, like `SavehighScore("myhighscores.dat")`.

Comment: This is a comment in general, how would you call it to save for a file. Would I do it through a key press, like I had done for my 'test.txt'.

Answer (score 1):

SavehighScore requires you supply a filename

```
case State.Gameover:
                {
                    //Get keyboard state
                    KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
                    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Back))
                    {
                        if (IsHighScore())
                        {
                            highScore = playerScore;

/////////////////////////  HERE  ///////////////////////////////////////////
SavehighScore("HighScoreFileName.txt");


}
                    playerScore = 0;
                    sharks.Clear();
                    crew.Clear();
                    gameState = State.Menu;
                }
                break;
            }
```

when you define a method with a type and Identifier in the parenthesis it's a parameter

```
private void SavehighScore(string filename /*I am a parameter*/)
```

every time you call the method you must provide a value for all parameters unless you provide a default value

```
private void SavehighScore(string filename = "some constant value")
```

all parameters with default values must appear after parameters without default values

so you can fix this 3 ways

1. see above

2.provide default value

3 remove the parameter and hardcode the filename inside the method.

well you can fix it more ways than that but you get idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. Sorry if I may seem illiterate in this subject  by posting petty problems :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an XNA problem, it's a C# problem.

The problem is that you have declared `SavehighScore` as

`private void SavehighScore(string filename)`

and therefore the compiler will not allow you to write `SavehighScore()` because you just told it that `SavehighScore` has to be given a string argument called `filename`. You have to supply a value for this argument in order to call the function.

You have two options

#### Rewrite the call to SavehighScore to include the missing argument:

```
 if (IsHighScore()){
         highScore = playerScore;
         SavehighScore(@"C:\MyGame\Saves\Highscore.dat"); //for example
  }
```

#### Provide a default value for the argument to SavehighScore

(assuming you are using C# 4 and Visual Studio 2010 or later)

```
private void SavehighScore(string filename=@"C:\MyGame\Saves\Highscore.dat")
```

This will allow you to call `SavehighScore` without any arguments.

> Personally I don't like option 2, but both are valid approaches as far as the compiler is concerned.